# Calling an activity after the screen password is verified---android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in android. I have screen password enabled. Means you have to enter a pin to unlock it.

Now , I want to call an activity, if some one enters a wrong screen password. Is it possible. If yes please let me know how ?

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. Do you want to call an activity if the user enters an invalid pin (which is already configured)?

If so, just check if it's correct and launch the activity as always.

```
    if (checkPin(thePin)) 
        startActivity(new Intent(context,CorrectPinActivity.class));
    else 
        startActivity(new Intent(context,WrongPinActivity.class));
```

If you mean another thing, please comment so, and will look into it :)

Comment: I want to call my activity after a wrong pin is entered. I am using the android screen lock.

Answer (score 0):

Let's guess you have an edittext called "txtPassword" and have a variable "rightPassword" in which you have the correct password stored.

Just check for this:

if(txtPassword.getText().toString() == rightPassword)
{
   // start the new activity here.
}
else
{
  // alert user for wrong password.
}

Comment: I want to call my activity after a wrong pin is entered. I am using the android screen lock.